# Who is Frieza's mom?

Tags: dragon-ball

Is there any evidence or mention of who Frieza's mother is in any of the new *Dragon Ball Super, Dragon Ball Z , Dragon Ball GT*, or any of the manga?

Comment: As a trivia: in the **totally non-canon** *Dragon Ball AF* (fan-made) manga drawn by Dragon Ball Super mangaka [Toyotarou](https://dragonball.fandom.com/wiki/Toyotar%C5%8D), Frieza's mother was the [West Supreme Kai](http://dragonballaffanon.wikia.com/wiki/Western_Supreme_Kai)...

Answer (score 2):

## Unclear

We have **never** seen a female member of Frieza's race, let alone Frieza's mother.

As for mentions of her in the anime, note that Frieza's mother is only referenced in the English dub of *Dragon Ball Z*, not in the original (where only a "father" is mentioned).  It could very well be that this race was intended to be unisex, which is a possibility [raised here](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Frieza%27s_race).  In the video game *Budokai Tenkaichi 3*, there are brief mentions of a "mother".

The [wikia article on Frieza's mother](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Frieza%27s_mother) concurs:

> Frieza mentions his "parents"/"loving parents" to Goku on Namek in the manga, anime, and *Dragon Ball Z: Battle of Z*, whereas he simply mentions "his father" to Goku in *Budokai Tenkaichi 3* and *Dragon Ball Z Kai*. **It should be mentioned that the plural form does not exist in Japanese and thus Frieza's mother is only mentioned in the English dub.**
>
> In Chi-Chi's commentary on First Form Frieza and Final Form Cooler in *Budokai Tenkaichi 3*, she mentions parents instead of just King Cold alone, stating that Frieza and Cooler's upbringing by their parents is a troublesome story. Chi-Chi also refers to Frieza's mother in King Cold's profile, wondering if Frieza's mother has the same face as Cold.